# Using regex to delete a special symbol in emacs

Tags: regex, emacs

I am trying to replace expressions like `silva:2018` to `silva2018`using replace regex in emacs. 
I had tried something like `[a-z]:[0-9]` to find the expression (in this example `a:2` but I don't know how to delete the symbol `:`.

Comment: Try `\([a-z]\):\([0-9]\)` and replace with `\1\2`

Comment: Would `\b:\b` work? I know it doesn't check for `alpha:numeric`, but you haven't specified that any other cases might be met

Comment: @ctwheels You are right I didn't specify that but it was what I intended to. Something like author:date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is straight forward with [Regexp Replacement](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html):

```
M-x replace-regexp <RET> \([a-z]\):\([0-9]\) <RET> \1\2 <RET>
```

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work. The error message is: `Invalid regexp: "Unmatched ) or \\)"`

Comment: You were right. It works. I must have typed something wrong.

Comment: Looking back at this answer, I really should have put quotes around "straight forward."